# Css Drop Line Menu Hover Problem

Tags: html, css

I have made a css dropline menu. It's works fine, but there's a small issue if i go to the child menu, the parent menu text color should be hover text color(#ccc;), but it's move default color(#000;).

Here Jsfiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/thilakar/aTXbm/4/

Please help me out with this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you have the hover-effect on the link. You'll have to use :hover on the li to have the hover effect even when you're hovering a submenu.

Change

```
.menu ul li a:hover
```

To

```
.menu ul li:hover a
```

And I think you'll get the effect you're after.